# GitHub Desktop and Visual Studio. Why directories are not deleted when changing branches?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

I apologize for my bad english.

I created new solution and project in VS for my C# console app. After that, I created a new local repository in the GHD for the solution folder, created exepions file .gitignore for .vs and binary files in project directory (bin and obj). Then i commit existing files. Ok, what about new project? I`m creating new branch in GHD and new project in the same solution. Update .gitignore file for new binares in new project folder (bin and obj). Then i commit the new files. After that i want to return to master branch and... and new project directory int solution folder is not removing. Also, in Solution Explorer new project is not removing too.

What i do wrong?

Comment: So, if im understanding correctly, you create a directory, commit it, change the branch and it stays? Has it occured to you that creating a branch off of the main branch with the file will keep that file unless you explicitly remove it?

Comment: @Frontear, If i will do the same things without a visual studio, creating and removing of some directories will complete correctly. I think that problem in how VS creating and refreshing its system files when i creating new project.

Comment: No, VS creates a .gitignore which automatically handles which files will be able to get commited. Is that your issue? Are you trying to delete files that git is ignoring?

Comment: @Frontear, ok, i created a new solution with auto generated .gitignore file, created a new local repository for it, created a new branch, created a new project and commited new project's files. Then i changed branch to master and in Solution Explorer new project still exist. In solution directory after branch changing new project folder is exist too. I don't understand, is it ok?

Comment: Normally that shouldn't be happening. What git client are you using

Comment: @Frontear, GItHub Desktop.

Comment: Just to be clear: Is only visual studio still showing the project that shouldn't be there, or also windows explorer?